# Gunicorn status is active(running) but service is disabled

Tags: django, deployment, gunicorn, wsgi, systemctl

when I run 'sudo systemctl gunicorn status', it shows to me :

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)

Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-02-06 11:55:05 EET; 23min ago
```

I cant figure out why it is disabled.

here is my gunicorn.service :

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target
[Service]
User=arh
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/arh/toy-model/server
ExecStart=/home/arh/toy-model/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/arh/toy-model/server/server.sock server.wsgi:application
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Have you enabled it previously via `sudo systemctl enable gunicorn`?

Comment: no, now it works, thx.